HOC image hover component not targeting pseudo element with Tailwind CSS
I am using Astro and Tailwind CSS.
Why is the following not working?
I have this HOC HoverScale.astro component:
// HoverScale.astro
<span class="[&>img]:group-hover:scale-105 group [&>img]:transition [&>img]:duration-300 [&>img]:ease-in-out">
  <slot />
</span>

I am using it in another component like:
<a href="foo">
  <HoverScale>
    <Picture
      src={url}
      alt={title}
    />
  </HoverScale>
</a>

This Picture component renders an <img /> tag.
When I add the Tailwind utilities transition duration-300 ease-in-out lg:group-hover:scale-105, directly on the Picture component it works fine.
Why isn't this working?

I don't see where HoverScale is used in your usage code snippet.

@Wongjn sorry added to the question. Thanks

First, consider checking:

The viewport is larger than the lg breakpoint.
You have 10 as a value for scale:
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      scale: {
        '10': 'your value here',



Furthermore, you'd need to ensure there is an ancestor element with the group class for the group-hover: to work:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      scale: {
        10: '0.1',
      },
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<a href="foo" class="group">
  <span class="group-hover:[&>img]:lg:scale-10 group [&>img]:transition [&>img]:duration-300 [&>img]:ease-in-out">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  </span>
</a>



Or if you intend for the hover to activate on the <span> element itself, you'd need to revise the variants to not use group at all:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      scale: {
        10: '0.1',
      },
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<a href="foo">
  <span class="[&>img]:hover:lg:scale-10 [&>img]:transition [&>img]:duration-300 [&>img]:ease-in-out">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  </span>
</a>




Can you try if it's working with Astro Picture component. With normal <img /> tag it's working fine.

The Astro Picture component renders the following:
<source srcset="foo">
<source srcset="foo">
<img src="foo" />
</picture>

